# Generating PDF from complex html table using JSPDF

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to generate pdf from html using JSPDF and html having one complex table, Added image below.

[image]

You can see in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/viswa317/xzZ7n/2123/), What i tried so far.

```
pdf.fromHTML(
source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
margins.left, // x coord
margins.top, { // y coord
    'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
},

function (dispose) {
    // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF 
    //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
    pdf.save('Test.pdf');
}, margins);
```

Problem is, when i try to generate pdf i am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Is it possible to use JSPDF for this kind of complex table or will it only work for a simple table.

**EDIT:**
**Solved this by different way, This is what i did**

1. I converted HTML Table into Canvas html2canvas.js
2. You can get canvas as Base64 image using `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"`)
3. Once i got Base64 image, Created empty PDF using JSPDF and using addImage feature of JSPDF, i manage to embed Base64 image inside PDF.

If you need charts and images as part of PDF -> [charts and images as part of PDF](https://csrviswa.medium.com/salesforce-lightning-how-to-generate-pdf-with-charts-and-images-f10f5dfef45e)

*Credit goes to my brain.*

Comment: Hi @Viswa, I have the same problem. Could you please update the Fiddle so that I can get a clear idea of your solution.  Thanks

Comment: Hi Viswa, I am facing ame issue as I have complex table to display. I am trying your apporach, but in any case i get "TypeError : html2canvas is not a function" error. I have included this js and also it is available in document when i search it in console. Can you suggest something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Bhagyashri are you sure that you are getting html2canvas function in the console and one more thing is that if browser can't find html2canvas it will throw  "html2canvas is not defined", But you are getting  TypeError.

Comment: I am sure that I get the html2canvas in console. and now I have this solved but "onrendered" is not being called. I don't have any error. So i have posted a question.

Comment: can you please send your updated code facing similar issue

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this by modifying line 6203 of jspdf.debug.js (on version 1.2.61) to this:

```
while (j < tableRow.cells.length && headers[j] != undefined) {
```

Which was originally:

```
while (j < tableRow.cells.length) {
```

Alternatively, I could make it go away by adding another td to the tr it was processing (it only had one td, which apparently caused the problem).

I'm thinking I'll try to submit it as a bug fix.

Comment: Cool,  please submit it as a bug. Will help others.

Answer (score 2):

1. Checkout the [*pdfmake Playground*](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) (It is supposed to work in the browser and is MIT-licensed.)
2. Select TABLES in the top menu of the *Playground*.
3. Scroll down the example pdf, there is a section illustrating Colspan-capabilities.

Comment: This colspan example shows how to generate PDF from a JavaScript object, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I stepped through the code using the chrome debugger, and it looks like jspdf is is having an issue with colspan in the first row of the table.

It seems like a bug in their library, where you can't use col span in the header or first row of each table.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Is there any other way  ?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could design your form with out using colspan. Use css to hide the appropriate cell borders?

Comment: I can't see any other options, it looks like the plugin just doesn't support this feature yet. You could contact the developer, or fork the repo and make the changes yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove All the colspan Attribute And Rowspan Attribute  From td Tag And Apply blank td then try.**

> Its Working and Generate Pdf  (for checking put this code in your file)

```
<div id="inspectionReport">
    <div class="title">
        <p class="appname">Title</p>
        <p>REPORT</p>
    </div>
    <p class="date">Revised on 9/3/2013</p>
    <p style="float:right;">
        <button onclick="javascript:demoFromHTML();">Generate Pdf</button>
    </p>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>A No : <span id="a">1</span>
                </td>
                <td>B / No : <span id="b">2</span>
                </td>
                <td>C Date: <span id="c"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>A No : <span id="d">3</span>
                </td>
                <td>B name: <span id="e">4</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>C [ X ] D [ ]</p>
                    <p>G Date : <span id="f"></span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>O No : <span id="yy"></span>
                </td>
                <td>Orgin : <span id="yyr"></span>
                </td>
                <td>S : [ X ] G [ ] J [ X ] Y [ X ] G</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Name : <span id="QW"></span>
                </td>
                <td>xc : <span id="FG"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No : <span id="gg"></span>
                </td>
                <td>company : <span id="gg"></span>
                </td>
                <td>type t [ ] A [ X ] No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quen : <span id="odrQuan"></span>
                </td>
                <td>Sh : <span id="shipQuan"></span>
                </td>
                <td>Run [ ] Int [ X ]. Shi [ ] No.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>   
                <td >Title:</td>

            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td>FY</td>
                <td>CJK</td>
                <td>SL</td>
                <td>F</td>
                <td>P</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td><span id="fyavail">20</span>
                </td>
                <td><span id="ck">40</span>
                </td>
                <td><span id="sl">70</span>
                </td>
                <td><span id="finish">100</span>
                </td>
                <td><span id="pack">50</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody id="dhtml">
            <tr>
                <td  class="boldFont">SAPC:</td>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>


            </tr>
            <tr class="boldFont">
                <td>ATU: <span id="aqluser"></span>
                </td>
                <td>SS : <span id="sampleSize"></span>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td >MA : <span id="majallowed"></span>
                </td>


                <td></td>
                <td>MAS : <span id="minallowed"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DT</td>
                <td align="center">No.</td>
                <td>DD</td>
                <td align="center">C</td>
                <td align="center">Max</td>
                <td align="center">Min</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >FY</td>
                <td align="center">1</td>
                <td>FY</td>
                <td align="center">11</td>
                <td align="center">12</td>
                <td align="center">123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td></td>

                <td align="center">2</td>
                <td>FY</td>
                <td align="center">11</td>
                <td align="center">12</td>
                <td align="center">123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">ST :</td>
                <td align="center">22</td>
                <td align="center">24</td>
                <td align="center">246</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >SKL</td>
                <td align="center">1</td>
                <td>SKL</td>
                <td align="center">14</td>
                <td align="center">13</td>
                <td align="center">234</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">2</td>
                <td>SKL</td>
                <td align="center">14</td>
                <td align="center">13</td>
                <td align="center">234</td>
                                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">ST :</td>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
                <td align="center">28</td>
                <td align="center">26</td>
                <td align="center">468</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >A</td>
                <td align="center">1</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td align="center">33</td>
                <td align="center">445</td>
                <td align="center">33</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td></td>
                <td align="center">2</td>
                <td>A</td>
                <td align="center">33</td>
                <td align="center">445</td>
                <td align="center">33</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">ST :</td>

                <td align="center">66</td>
                <td align="center">890</td>
                <td align="center">66</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>


                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right" class="boldFont">Tot :</td>

                <td align="center">116</td>
                <td align="center">940</td>
                <td align="center">780</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr class="boldFont">
            <td >Title 3</td>
            <td  align="center">ASD</td>
             <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="boldFont">
            <td>C : <span id="tolcartons"></span>
            </td>
            <td>S : <span id="samsize"></span>
            </td>
            <td>M : <span id="allowmajor"></span>
            </td>
            <td  align="center">WPZ</td>

             <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D No.</td>
            <td>D type</td>
            <td>NOF</td>
            <td>C</td>
            <td>Spev</td>
            <td>Act</td>
            <td>diff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>F/Y</td>
            <td><span id="nooffy"></span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>S/K/L</td>
            <td><span id="skl"></span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Fin</td>
            <td><span id="finl"></span>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  align="right">TM:</td>
            <td><span id="totmajores"></span>
            </td>

             <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

            <td >Comment:<span id="comment"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td >outcome</td>
                <td>A. V</td>
                <td>[ X ] P</td>
                <td>[ ] F</td>
                <td>[ ] W</td>
                <td>[ ] NA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>B. M</td>
                <td>[ X ] P</td>
                <td>[ ] F</td>
                <td>[ ] W</td>
                <td>[ ] NA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td></td>
                <td>C. P</td>
                <td>[ X ] P</td>
                <td>[ ] F</td>
                <td>[ ] W</td>
                <td>[ ] NA</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="boldFont">
                <td>CC A s</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span id="comcorraction"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="boldFont">
                <td >Title 4 :</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TWT [ X ] Pass [ ] Fail</td>
                <td>STO [ ] Pass [ X ] Fail</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PAS [ ] A [ X ] NA</td>
                <td>SR [ ] Yes [ X ] No [ ] NA</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="boldFont">
                <td >Signatures:</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p><span id="qaauditNo">.</span>  <span id="qaadate" class="sdate">.</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>QANo <span class="sdate">Date</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><span id="mp">.</span>  <span id="mpdate" class="sdate">.</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>MP<span class="sdate">Date</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><span id="supr">.</span>  <span id="supdate" class="sdate">.</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>Sup<span class="sdate">Date</span>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<p class="boldFont">Note: ABCDEFG</p>
<p class="boldFont">Note: ABCDEFG</p>
<div class="title boldFont">QC / MED / FAC / FOR</div>
```